Как завершить взаимодействие с кнопкой Disnake
У меня есть прослушиватель on_button_click, в котором прослушиваются все нажатия кнопок. Но у меня есть взаимодействие, редактирующее исходное сообщение, в котором при нажатии кнопок выскакивает "Ошибка взаимодействия". Я пробовал в конце участка кода вставлять return, но не венчалось успехом.
Код (часть вырезана, так как код огромный):
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_button_click(self, inter: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    button_id = inter.component.custom_id
    message_inter: disnake.Message = inter.message
    guild = inter.guild
    author: disnake.User = inter.author

    if button_id.startswith("leaderboard_"):
        data = button_id.split("_")

        page = int(data[2])

        if data[1] == "balance":
            data = then.get_balance_top(page)

            next_page = False
            if data["pages"] > 1 and page < data["pages"]:
                next_page = True

            prev_page = False
            if page != 1:
                prev_page = True

            components = [
                disnake.ui.Button(
                    style = disnake.ButtonStyle.gray,
                    emoji = Icon.back,
                    disabled = not prev_page,
                    custom_id = f"leaderboard_balance_{page}_b"
                ),
                disnake.ui.Button(
                    style = disnake.ButtonStyle.gray,
                    emoji = Icon.refresh,
                    custom_id = f"leaderboard_balance_{page}_r"
                ),
                disnake.ui.Button(
                    style = disnake.ButtonStyle.gray,
                    emoji = Icon.forward,
                    custom_id = f"leaderboard_balance_{page}_f",
                    disabled = not next_page
                )
            ]
            color = config.embed_color
            message = disnake.Embed(
                title = f"{Icon.money} Топ баланса сервера",
                timestamp = inter.created_at,
                color = color
            )

            await message_inter.edit(embed = message, components = components)


Если вы хотите чтоб кнопка(и) была доступна всегда:\

Если создавали кнопку(и) через View:
Укажите параметр timeout none:

view = disnake.ui.View(timeout=None)

Если отправили кнопки через components, то ошибки быть не должно

Если вы хотите убрать сообщение "Ошибка взаимодействия", но оставить кнопку неактивной, то, насколько мне известно, это нельзя сделать.

Удачи, отпишитесь если нужно что-то еще!
